# Can someone explain the relation between the Functions parameter in my code sample

Tags: javascript

I have started a javascript course couple of days ago and in today's lesson i am not quite understanding the relation in the code and the tutor explanation was none existing.

Ok, i understand that i have;
Created a variable called `output` with the value `hello world`
Created a function called `welcome` with the parameter `message`

I am not understanding the relation between `output` and `message`.

why is the `console.log(message)` not `console.log(output)` which produces the same in the console.

```
let output = 'hello world'
let counter = 0

welcome(output)
welcome(output)
welcome(output)

function welcome(message) {
    counter++
    let temp = `${counter} times run`
    console.log(message)
    console.log(temp)
}
```

Create a function to output a message from a variable, into the console.
Invoke the function 3 times and increase the count variable each time.

Comment: you hand over a value to the function and this value has now a new variable, which is kind of a container for a value

Comment: So the output variable becomes message within the function.
but why not use output which produces the same in the console?

Comment: i dont know. ask the author.

Comment: Ok thank you, so going forward would i be doing it wrong to best practices if i use the output variable instead

Comment: As a side note: does the course tell you *not* to separate statements with a semi-colon? I would advise to use them though.

Comment: Are you sure the assignment is to increase the counter *inside* the function? It is not clear from what you quote.

Comment: @trincot yes, the only time they use the semi colon so far is on statements outside of the function. I think i need to find a better tutor/ course.
going forward i will end all statements with a semi-colon. thanks for pointing this out

Comment: yes, that code was taken from the end sample at the end of the lesson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite simple.

you created a variable `output` which has the value `Hello World`.

You also have function `welcome` where you give an argument `welcome` to.

when you use `welcome(output)` what you are basically doing is saying to your code to give the value `Hello World` to the function.

`output` and `message` are only related because you told your code to use the value for `output` to be used as the value given for `welcome`, but you aren't limited to just adding that.

```
let output = 'hello world'
let counter = 0

welcome(output) // This will output "hello world" and "1 times run"
welcome(output) // This will output "hello world" and "2 times run"
welcome(output) // This will output "hello world" and "3 times run"
welcome("Hey man!") // This will output "Hey man!" and "4 times run"

function welcome(message) {
    counter++
    let temp = `${counter} times run`
    console.log(message)
    console.log(temp)
}
```

---

Another thing to not is that both `output` and `counter` are what we call **Global Variables**, which means they can be accessed by every scope that is nested inside their own scope (`welcome()` is inside the scope of your script, so it can access both `counter` and `output` without issue.
Let's change the code a bit to show what I mean, let's remove the `welcome` argument from the function.
The following code will still output *hello world* annd *x times run*, but cannot output anything else anymore.

```
let output = 'hello world'
let counter = 0

welcome() // This will output "hello world" and "1 times run"
welcome() // This will output "hello world" and "2 times run"
welcome() // This will output "hello world" and "3 times run"

function welcome() {
    counter++
    let temp = `${counter} times run`
    console.log(output)
    console.log(temp)
}
```

To summarize: the original code allows you to give a value along with your function that it then will use for something (in this case to output text).
The code is using the value of the global variable `counter` to keep track of how many times you have run your function.

I hope this clarified your question.

Comment: thank you AlexSNorth for taking the time to explain. The keyword you used that i was missing, `Argument`. `Message` variable is a parameter only meaningful inside the function and `output` is a argument of the `welcome` function. Got it.

Comment: You are welcome my man, welcome to the world of coding! The best of luck to you!